# How to alter composables created from a list

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a row, where I insert some composables with a list I have, i.e.:

```kotlin
  val isSelected = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

  Card {
    list.forEach { item -> 
      CustomView(isPressed = isSelected)
    }
  }
```

The Card view has some other tests in it, so it is not solely the list's items.

In my `CustomView()` I use the isPressed to determine what color the selected items background should be.

This is just some pseudo code. When I click CustomView, it changes color, and when I click it again, it reverts. That's fine.
But I also need to be able to click anywhere else on the `Card()`, so it changes the color on the single item.

I tried to add an `isSelected` to the list's objects, but that did nothing as well.

I hope it's clear what my goal is. I uploaded a video to show what it currently does: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UyHGN.jpg

It seems like it did not record where I click, so I'll try to explain it. I click on a vertical bar and it turns pink and the text shows relevant informations. When I click elsewhere, the text goes back to show default values, the vertical bar does not revert. I need the vertical bar to go back to purple again, not being focused.

Comment: Please upload a video showing your problems, if possible

Comment: @Abhimanyu I have uploaded a video, hopefully explaining the issue a bit better.